# PHP curl failing to resolve IPv6-only URL

Tags: php, curl, ipv6

I'm trying to get data from `http://ipv6.test-ipv6.com`, which only has AAAA IPv6 record (no IPv4). I can get the data from command line like `curl -v http://ipv6.test-ipv6.com` (shows that the IP is resolved properly). I also tried `dig AAAA ipv6.test-ipv6.com @127.0.0.1` and it works fine, as well as getting the data when I specify the IP in PHP curl call: `$ch = curl_init('http://[2001:470:1:18::119]');`. But specifically using the IPv6-only hostname fails. How do I fix this?

Code:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init('http://ipv6.test-ipv6.com');
//$ch = curl_init('http://[2001:470:1:18::119]');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_VERSION_IPV6);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Actually by the looks of it, the problem is with `CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE` options - it works without that option. What I want to achieve is to get curl to use IPv6 address or fail if it's unavailable. Isn't that what `CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE` should do?

Comment: Can you show the code that fails? You say that DNS resolving works and that CURL works with the IPv6-only hostname. From your question it is not clear what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: @Sander Steffann, added code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expectations of `CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE` are correct, that is indeed what it is supposed to do. However you seem to have used a wrong constant for the value. From the manual:

> **CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE**: Allows an application to select what kind of IP
>   addresses to use when resolving host names. This is only interesting
>   when using host names that resolve addresses using more than one
>   version of IP, possible values are **CURL_IPRESOLVE_WHATEVER**,
>   **CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4**, **CURL_IPRESOLVE_V6**, by default
>   **CURL_IPRESOLVE_WHATEVER**.

I can't find the constant you use (`CURL_VERSION_IPV6`) in the manual, so IIRC then PHP will interpret it as the string `"CURL_VERSION_IPV6"` which won't work.

Comment: Thank you, `CURL_VERSION_IPV6` is defined as a constant used in curl_version to tell if curl is ipv6 capable in php

Comment: Ah, I missed that one. Thanks!