# Can we use IPV6 in CURL?

Tags: php, curl, ipv6

I have got IPV6 Range on my dedicated server, 
It looks like this: `1234:6c80:5:0::/64`
I want to use IPV6 address in `CURLOPT_INTERFACE` and I am using `WHM/cPanel on CentOS 7`
Is it possible to use that range/block in my `CURL` functions?

Comment: Did you give it a try?

Comment: If not this Q & A [might be a useful read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25309713/php-curl-failing-to-resolve-ipv6-only-url)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Actually i don't know how can i use that range as CURLOPT_INTERFACE, please let me know if you know that!